# How to Lock Oracle table for update using C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I have a table on Oracle and I need when a user is updating no other user can update on the same time.

only 1 user can update at each time.

the database is Oracle and the application language is C#

thank you for help

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverlfow. Please take the [Tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, Oracle seems to already have this documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9015.htm)

Comment: Why do you need this? Oracle takes care of proper locking fully automatically.

Comment: Start transaction. Update/insert/delete. Commit.

Comment: Seems exactly what a Transactions does.

Answer (score 0):

That's a strange requirement; database vendors do everything they can to make many concurrent users work without problems, and now you want to do the opposite. Oh well.

- At the beginning, lock the table in exclusive mode so that only you have access to it: `lock table your_table in exclusive mode nowait;` . `NOWAIT` will notify other users that it is locked; otherwise, their session would have to wait until you release the lock. That manifests as if nothing is happening; cursor blinks "indefinitely" and people usually think that something's wrong with the database
- do whatever you plan to do
- `commit;` to release the lock

Comment: thank you for answering my question, can I lock the table by transaction.  because I want to update quantity field and I do not want concurrent users to update the quantity of product on the same time.

Comment: You don't have to do anything "special" - update quantity and commit once you're done. Nobody will be able to update the same row until you commit (or rollback).